# SQL Server : week end as Friday and prior week as end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am creating a report which reports revenue details for Prior Week, Month to Week, Quarter to Week, and Total, all based on the cut off `date` as prior week.

Assuming the report will always be run on Fridays, the calculation/ cut off dates would be as follows :

- Report Run Date: `08-12-2016`
- Prior Week: `07-30-2016` until `08-05-2016`
- Month to Week: `08-01-2016` until `08-05-2016`
- Quarter to date: Start of Quarter date from today's date until `08-05-2016`

Now assuming if I ran this report on Wednesday `08-03-2016`, then it should use the current end of week as 08-05-2015 and then go back a week. In that case the Cut off date would be `08-23-2016` until `08-29-2016`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to work out Last Friday, one using `DATEFIRST` and the other using the coincidence that Day 0 was a Monday.

Set `DATEFIRST` to 6 (Saturday), then work out the previous end of week day:

```
SET DATEFIRST 6
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,  -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS DATE) 'Last Friday';
```

Or find the most recent start of week (Monday) and count back three days:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -3 , DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,GETDATE()),0)) AS DATE) 'Last Friday'
```

I prefer the former but since you're looking explicitly for Friday, not the locale specific end of the week day, you'll be OK with the latter.

The rest is plugging into standard First/Last `DATEADD/DATEDIFF` patterns. These should give you what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @LastFriday DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -3 , DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,GETDATE()),0));

SELECT 
    LastFriday = @LastFriday, 
    PriorWeekStart = DATEADD(DAY, -6, @LastFriday),
    MonthStart = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @LastFriday), 0) AS DATE),
    QuarterStart = CAST(DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, @LastFriday), 0) AS DATE)

LastFriday PriorWeekStart MonthStart QuarterStart
---------- -------------- ---------- ------------
2016-07-29 2016-07-23     2016-07-01 2016-07-01
```